# Is there a way to simplify this code and get the same answer?

Tags: python

```
myList = [2,4,3,5,6,7,1]
def largest(myList):
    maxNumber = myList[0]
    for element in myList:
        if element > maxNumber:
            maxNumber = element
    return maxNumber
print(largest(myList))
```

Comment: `max(myList)` is simpler...

Comment: Here's the built-in `max()` function: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#max.  So `max(myList)` would give you the same answer as your function.

Comment: If you insist on using your own max function I would advise to add a check if the list is empty, right now it will just fail with an index error (because of `myList[0]`). But that does the exact opposite of what you asked...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use the built-in `max`

```py
myList = [2,4,3,5,6,7,1]
print(max(myList))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

`largest = max(myList)`